# Setting an initial value of an extra field on a ModelForm from an UpdateView

Tags: django, forms

I have a form which is a modelform with two extra fields. In my model, it includes a PointField which is made up of an easting and northing (the X & Y components of the Point). On my modelform, I do not display the PointField and instead display two DecimalFields for the easting and northing:

```
class QuoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
  easting = forms.DecimalField()
  northing = forms.DecimalField()
  class Meta:
    model = Quote
    fields = ('desc', 'client', 'contact', 'amount', 'easting', 'northing', 'note')      

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['note'].required = True
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_method = 'post'
    self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Save Quote')
    )
```

For my CreateView I include a form_valid that takes the easting and northing and turns them into a point and updates the PointField record.

For my UpdateView, I want to go backwards from the PointField and populate the Easting and Northing DecimalFields on my form.

I am stuck on how to "pass" this information to my form.

I tried a get_form in my UpdateView like this, but it fails:

```
class QuoteUpdateView(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
  permission_required = 'jobs.update_quote'
  redirect_field_name = 'dashboard'
  model = Quote
  form_class = QuoteForm    
  template_name = "jobs/quote_form.html"
  template_name_suffix = '_form'
  
  def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    form = super().get_form(form_class)
    quote = self.object
    pt = quote.ptgeom
    pt.transform(2953)
    form.fields['easting'] = pt[0]
    form.fields['northing'] = pt[1]
    return form

  def form_valid(self, form):     
    quote = form.save(commit=False)
    quote.ptgeom = geos.Point((form.cleaned_data['easting'], form.cleaned_data['northing']), srid=2953)
    quote.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)

  def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('quote_detail', kwargs={'pk' : self.object.id})
```

In my approach so far, I am using the same form for both the create and update view. It feels like I could create a different form and use something like get_context_data to find the correct record, then update the fields, but this doesn't feel like the correct approach?

Is there a way to set these values from the UpdateView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab and alter the intial values of fields in your `get_form` function via `get_initial`, included in the updateview.

```
  def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    form = super().get_form(form_class)
    quote = self.object
    pt = quote.ptgeom
    pt.transform(2953)
    #set form initial values
    initial_values = self.get_initial() 
    initial_values['easting'] = pt[0]
    initial_values['northing'] = pt[1]
    form.initial = initial_values
    return form
```

Update after comment

You might try doing the same thing in get_initial itself, in case the above interferes with an order of actions.

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial_values = super().get_initial()
    quote = self.object
    pt = quote.ptgeom
    pt.transform(2953)
    initial_values['easting'] = pt[0]
    initial_values['northing'] = pt[1]
    return initial_values
```

Comment: This works to populate the values of these two fields, but seems to break the link to the model for the other fields? All the other fields show up empty instead of populated with the "current" values for the update. I can populate them by adding them in here, but is there a way to "mix" the two? As in all the rest of the fields are linked to the model, but I can update only the initial values of these two fields?

Comment: Hmm. I've added another approach.